# Unable to set document name according to user email

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add the documents as user email address I am finding error on `.add()` function.

```
class Services{
  addCard(token){
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user){
      Firestore.instance
          .collection('cards')
          .document(user.email)
          .add({
        'tokenid': token.tokenId,
        'Email': user.email,
        'customerid': 'new'
      }).then((val){
      });
      print("saveedd");
    });
  }
}
```

Code is running fine like this. but I do not want to put data in new collection in token collection

```
class Services{
  addCard(token){
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user){
      Firestore.instance
          .collection('cards')
            .document(user.email)
          .collection('tokens').add({
      'tokenid': token.tokenId,
      'Email': user.email,
      'customerid': 'new'
      }).then((val){
      });
      print("saveedd");
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer you can set the document name as you want but for that purpose you need to `.setData` instead of `.add`.

```
class Services{
  addCard(token){
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user){
      Firestore.instance
          .collection('cards')
          .document(user.email)
          .setData({
        'Email': user.email,

      }).then((val){

      });
      print("saveedd");
    });
  }
}
```

according to above code you can set these as field of the specific documents if you want to add new collection you can run your above code to make new collection name.